# Using a List<Child class> in a method parameter requiring List<Parent class>

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have an abstract class call `Task` that is inherited by `Task1`

```java
public abstract class Task<STATUS extends Enum> {
  STATUS getStatus();
  void setStatus(STATUS status);
}

public class Task1 extends Task<TaskStatusEnum> {
  private TaskStatusEnum status;

  public Task1() {}

  public TaskStatusEnum getStatus() { return status; }
  public void setStatus(TaskStatusEnum status) { this.status = status; }
}

// Task2, Task3, Task4, ...

public enum TaskStatusEnum {
  PLANNED, STARTED, FINISH, FAILED;
}
```

I'm trying to create a class who's goal is to update the tasks status

```java
public class StateMachine {
  public StateMachine() {}

  public void startMultipleTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    tasks.stream().forEach(task -> task.setStatus(TaskStatusEnum.STARTED));
  }
}
```

Why does this not compile :

```java
Task1 myTask = new Task1();
StateMachine stateMachine = new StateMachine();

List<Task1> allTasks = List.of(myTask);

stateMachine.startMultipleTasks(allTasks); // Compilation error ; Required type: List<Task> Provided: List<Task1>
```

But this does :

```java
Task1 myTask = new Task1();
StateMachine stateMachine = new StateMachine();

stateMachine.startMultipleTasks(List.of(myTask));
```

I know that I could store the variable `allTasks` in a `List<Task>`, but I need a `List<Task1>` later on in my code.

NOTE : I'm using Java 17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are invariant, so `List<Task1>` is not considered a subtype of `List<Task>` although `Task1` extends `Task`. You could instead use a [bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) for the parameter.

```java
public void startMultipleTasks(List<? extends Task> tasks)
```